# Is there any reason React Redux Connect returns a function and not a component directly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, higher-order-components

I am trying to understand more about higher order components and my understanding is the typical pattern is like this:

```
const HOC = (WrappedComponent) => {
    ...
    return class extends React.Component {
        render(){
            <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />
        }
    }
}
```

Which you could call like this: `HOC(CustomComponent)`

However many popular libraries including react-redux instead return a function that in turn returns the component:

```
const connect = (mapStateToProps) => {
    ...
    const storeToPass = mapStateToProps(store)
    return function(WrappedComponent) {
        return class extends React.Component {
            render(){
                <WrappedComponent {...this.props, ...storeToPass} />
            }
        }
    }
}
```

which you would call like this: `connect(mapState)(CustomComponent)`

My question is why? Is there any reason for this or is it just a preference on pattern?  Why couldn't you do this for the connect function?

```
const connect = (mapStateToProps, WrappedComponent) => {
    ...
    const storeToPass = mapStateToProps(store)
    return class extends React.Component {
        render(){
            <WrappedComponent {...this.props, ...storeToPass} />
        }
    }
}
```

And call it like this: `Connect(MapState, CustomComponent)`

Is there any difference?

Comment: Apart from easier partial application, I do not see any other advantage for the 1st method over the 2nd.

Comment: Natural connect.js doesn't return function or class component, it returns special object with props. That "model" that you represented is not real in react, and doesn't have nothing in common with natural model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one thing, `connect` accepts (up to) four arguments: `mapStateToProps`, `mapDispatchToProps`, `mergeProps` and `options`. https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect#connect

Of course in theory the function signature could have been flipped to `connect(Component, mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps, mergeProps, options)`.

However, the reason given from the documentation:

> you may use the hoc to enable different components to get the same behavior

Their example is giving two different components login/logout actions:

```js
// first call: returns a hoc that you can use to wrap any component
const connectUser = connect(
  mapState,
  mapDispatch
)

// second call: returns the wrapper component with mergedProps
// you may use the hoc to enable different components to get the same behavior
const ConnectedUserLogin = connectUser(Login)
const ConnectedUserProfile = connectUser(Profile)
```

https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect#connect-returns

Comment: Great explanation, and just what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but in addition to @anthonygood's answer, there is another reason which has to do with using multple HOCs. See the react docs on HOCs. Briefly, instead of having to chain calls to HOCs you can compose them as shown in the code snippet below taken directly from REACT docs on HOCs.

```
// Instead of doing this...
const EnhancedComponent = withRouter(connect(commentSelector)(WrappedComponent))

// ... you can use a function composition utility
// compose(f, g, h) is the same as (...args) => f(g(h(...args)))
const enhance = compose(
  // These are both single-argument HOCs
  withRouter,
  connect(commentSelector)
)
const EnhancedComponent = enhance(WrappedComponent)
```

Answer (score 0):

The concept of HOC in react was introduced later after the redux library. And the function itself is known as a component in react. So, you know the deal; it's pretty complex to change everything that already is published. If it has to implement the way react hook is implemented then there would be blunder changes required by most of the softwares.

Answer (score 0):

`Connect` returns a function because this function needs to be very flexible which in turns means it has to take many customization options as arguments. Surely `CustomComponent` could be just another argument passed to `Connect` so that you would have `HOC(CustomComponent, option1, ...optionN)`.

Another and neater option taken by Redux creators was to pass all the customization options as arguments to Connect separately and in return get another function, already customized. This customized function then takes `CustomComponent` as the only argument.